# CiviCRM SendinBlue email integration

Tags: email

Has anyone in the CiviCRM community considered integrating CiviCRM with SendinBlue (https://www.sendinblue.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I am aware (and a google search, which I am sure you have done) does not bring up anything significant.

Aside: I'm interested in developing marketing automation tools for CiviCRM. Similar to sendinblue and dotmailer and would be happy to chat further with you if you're interested (michaelmcandrew@thirdsectordesign.org).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Sendinblue for a while.
Not using any extensions, just plugged in the SMTP credentials and emailing away

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it out. What version of CiviCRM are you currently running? How are your maintaining sync of contacts between Sendinblue and Civi?

Comment: I use 4.6.25 . I'm not keeping contacts in send in blue. Doing everything in civicrm